# how to monitor when tasks of dispatch queue in recursion all completed?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue

Normally I can use `DispatchGroup` to track the tasks in multiple Dispatch task. But in order to make sure  `DispatchGroup` works properly, the `group.notify` method has to be called after all of the `group.enter` are called for all the `task`s.

The questions for now is, I am having a recursion, and in the recursion it creates more `task`s, I want to make sure all of the `tasks` are completed. As I mentioned earlier, the `DispatchGroup.notify` won't work properly if it's called earlier than all the `group.enter`. In this recursion case you won't know when the which is the last `group.enter` call.

Simplist Example:

```
func findPath(node: Node) {
  if !node.isValid { return }
  queue.async { //concurrent queue
    findPath(node.north)
  }
  queue.async {
    findPath(node.west)
  }
  queue.async {
    findPath(node.south)
  }
  queue.async {
    findPath(node.east)
  }
}
```

This is the simplest example, in my case there are a lot more async blocks, like image fetching, network api call, etc. How would I make sure that the `findPath` function in this example would completely finished by all the tasks from the Dispatch queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure associated with the dispatchGroup.notify isn't called until the last dispatchGroup.leave is called, so you call `enter` *outside* the asynchronous task and `leave` *inside*

Something like:

```
func findPath(node: Node) {
  if !node.isValid { return }
  dispatchGroup.enter()
  queue.async { //concurrent queue
    findPath(node.north)
    dispatchGroup.leave()
  }

  dispatchGroup.enter()
  queue.async {
    findPath(node.west)
    dispatchGroup.leave()
  }

  dispatchGroup.enter()
  queue.async {
    findPath(node.south)
    dispatchGroup.leave()
  }

  dispatchGroup.enter()
  queue.async {
    findPath(node.east)
    dispatchGroup.leave()
  }
}


func findPaths(startNode: Node) {
    findPath(node: startNode)
    dispatchGroup.notify {
        print("All done")
    }
}
```

Comment: To pile on, if you need to spawn more tasks inside those queues, you can pass the DispatchGroup as a parameter.  The DispatchGroup is a thread safe class that you can update from anywhere.